# Como utilizar psr-4 no composer com diferentes subpastas

Tags: php, composer

Como configura meus diretorios no composewr.json,

Meus diretórios estão assim e não da certo

```
Vizuare
  -vendor
    -composer

    -php-class
       -src
         -DB
         -Model
         -Page.php


    -phpmailer
    -rain
    -slim
    -autoload.php

-views
-views-cache
composer.json
composer.lock
index.php
```

Por qual motivo não está dando certo minha estrutura de pasta?

Comment: Seus códigos estão em `php-class`? Existe o arquivo `composer.json` neste diretório? Qual o conteúdo dele? Quais são os *namespaces* nos arquivos PHP?

Comment: o PHP sim os HTML dentro de views

Comment: {
    "name": "Julio/vizuare",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Júlio Silva",
            "email": ""
        }
    ],
    "require": {
     "phpmailer/phpmailer":"5.2.22",
     "slim/slim":"2.0",
     "rain/raintpl":"3.0.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Vizuare\\": "vendor\\php-class\\src"
        }
    }
}

Comment: este e o meu composer

Comment: Mas esse arquivo está no diretório raiz ou dentro de `php-class`? Devem existir dois arquivos, um em cada diretório.

Comment: Depende muito dos namespaces que vai usar nos arquivos, eu pessoalmente recomendaria que usasse os namespaces como um esquema de "diretório", assim a organização é intuitiva e só precisará definir o "namespace principal". Só pra **constar**, a pasta vender geralmente deve contar as libs e pacotes 3rdparty, coisas como configurações, models e afins "da aplicação" deveriam ficar em outro lugar.

Comment: Minha pasta raiz e Vizuare e dentro deste diretorio esta minhas pastas o vendor, views, views-cache. dentro de vendor esta´ minhas pasta composer, class-php, phpmailer, rain e slim. Dentro de class-php estão todos os meus codigos php, e dentro de views estão minhas paginas html

Comment: Creio que esta você esta misturando `vendor` com a aplicação, não é este o propósito da pasta "vendor", acho que você não entendeu bem o que é o `composer` ainda, eu pessoalmente recomendo não usar ou estruturar algo que se você ainda não entende bem como funciona amigo. Você pode dar uma olhada em frameworks populares para ver como eles organizam os Models, Views e Controllers, um exemplo é o Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/structure (claro que não é pra seguir a risca, é só para entender e criar o seu)

Comment: Agradeço a dica, muito valiosa